# How can I align captions with each level of a tree drawn with tikz-qtree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-qtree

I have drawn a binary tree using the TikZ-qtree package.

1) I now would like to align captions on the right of tree with each of its level---and I would like the placement to be automatic (ideally I only have to specify that I want it at Xpx from the right border of the tree, and the vertical positioning is taken care of by itself).

2) I would like to be able to draw several brackets in the tree ranging some of the (contiguous) nodes. Ideally, again, I would only specify the nodes, and not have to take care about positioning at all!!

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\def\tn#1{{\bf #1}}    

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.0 
            [.0 
              [.0
                [.{\tn 0} ]
                [.{\tn 1} ] ]
              [.1 
                [.{\tn 2} ]
                [.{\tn 3} ] ] ]
            [.1
              [.2 
                [.{\tn 4} ]
                [.0 
                  [.{\tn 0} ]
                  [.{\tn 1} ] ] ]
              [.3 
                [.1
                  [.{\tn 2} ]
                  [.{\tn 3} ] ]
                [.2
                  [.{\tn 4} ]
                  [.0 \edge[roof]; {... } ] ] ] ] ]
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is an illustration of what I aim to do:

[image: Using a bitmap editing tool, this is what I would like to get (approximatively)]

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the captions, you can draw a second tree to the right of the first tree with the branch style set to `[draw=none]`.  This will ensure that the captions line up.

For underlining sets of nodes, you need to make the starting and ending nodes using the `\node` command, and then draw the underline.  For this part, I've used some very useful code supplied by [Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2552/jake), which implements in TikZ the equivalent of the PSTricks `\ncbar` command.

I've also removed your `\tn` macro, which is not needed, since you can define a separate style for each terminal (leaf) node in `tikz-qtree`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
% The following code is due to Jake
% and implements in tikz the equivalent of PSTrick's \ncbar command
% http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4527875#4527875
\tikzset{
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=(\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!#1!-90:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.25cm
}
% end Jake's code 

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every leaf node/.style={font=\bfseries}]
    \Tree [.0 
            [.0 
              [.0
                \node (0) {0}; 
                 1  ]
              [.1 
                2
                3 ] ]
            [.1
              [.2 
                \node (4) {4};
                [.0 
                  0
                  1 ] ]
              [.3 
                [.1
                  2
                  3 ]
                [.2
                  4
                  [.0 \edge[roof]; {... } ] ] ] ] ]
  \draw[ncbar=-.4cm] (0) to (4);
  \begin{scope}[xshift=2in]
  \tikzset{edge from parent/.append style={draw=none}, 
  every tree node/.append style={font=\sffamily\bfseries}
  }
  \Tree [[.{V=2} [.{V=4} [.{V=8} [.{V=5} ] ]]]]
  \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Both solutions are perfect. Thank you very much, this helps a lot. :)

Comment: This is more-or-less what I used to do in `qtree` but it got a bit more complicated. (Things can get non-aligned, and I had to have 3 trees and include hacks for overlay specifications.)

Comment: @cfr Yes, I agree, but for quick and dirty it's not too hard.  For more complex stuff your package is absolutely the way to go.

Comment: Indeed. I had a whole semester of proofs to set for Beamer and `qtree` was a pain. Even to do the incremental overlays required a hack, and then that hack had to be applied multiple times consistently to each of three trees for each proof. You can see why I wanted a `forest` solution ;).

Answer (score 3):

Here's the same tree typeset with version 0.05 of the experimental `justtrees.sty`. (Should you wish to play guinea pig for me, please let me know so I can give you a current version. An earlier version is somewhere on this site.)

Answering this question using `justtrees` let me to fix one more bug....

---

To add the labels at the right you just say `just=<label>` for any of the nodes at the appropriate level of the tree. Since the labels have `=` in them, they need protection with curly brackets in this case.

The bracketing of the groups of nodes is done with a new style `bracket me=<end node>`. This should be applied to the leftmost node of the group. The argument should be a reference (name or `forest` relative name or alias etc.) to the rightmost node of the group. I've bracketed 2 such groups just for demonstration purposes here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{justtrees}% version 0.05
\begin{document}
\begin{justtree}
  {
    /tikz/every node/.append style={font=\sffamily},
    /tikz/select/.style={font=\sffamily\bfseries},
    just format={font=\sffamily\bfseries},
    /forest/bracket me/.style={
      tikz+={\draw [thick] (.south west) +(0,5pt) |- (#1.south east) -- +(0,5pt);}
    }
  }
  [0
    [0, just={v=2}
      [0, just={v=4}
        [0, just={v=8}, select, bracket me=4]
        [1, select]
      ]
      [1
        [2, select]
        [3, select]
      ]
    ]
    [1
      [2
        [4, select, name=4]
        [0
          [0, select, bracket me=p]
          [1, select]
        ]
      ]
      [3
        [1
          [2, just={v=5}, select]
          [3, select]
        ]
        [2
          [4, select, name=p]
          [0
            [\dots, triangle]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{justtree}
\end{document}
```

[image: labels for tree]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `forest`:

```
  \begin{forest}
  label tree,
  for tree={
    circle,draw,
    s sep'=10pt, 
    edge+=thick,  
    font=\strut\footnotesize\sffamily,
  },
[A, name=lvl0
    [B
      [C, edge label={node[midway,left] {}} ] 
      [D] 
      [E
      [F]
      [G]
      ]
      ]
    [H, name=lvl1 
    [I
      [J]
      [K]
    ] 
      [L] 
      [M, name=lvl2 
      [N, name=lvl3
      ]
      ]
  ] 
]
\node[right=4.05cm of lvl0, Comment] {Level 0};
\node[right=1.75cm of lvl1, Comment] {Level 1};
\node[right=0.6cm of lvl2, Comment] {Level 2};
\node[right=0.6cm of lvl3, Comment] {Level 3};
\end{forest}
```

A minimal working code:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt]{beamer}
% \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{%
  label tree/.style={
    for tree={tier/.option=level},
    level label/.style={
      before typesetting nodes={
        for nodewalk={current,tempcounta/.option=level,group={root,tree breadth-first},ancestors}{if={>OR={level}{tempcounta}}{before drawing tree={label me=##1}}{}},
      }
    },
    before drawing tree={
      tikz+={\coordinate (a) at (current bounding box.north);},
    },
  },
  label me/.style={tikz+={\node [anchor=base west] at (.parent |- a) {#1};}},
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning}

\tikzset{%
    Comment/.style={%
        draw=none,
        inner sep=0mm,
        outer sep=0mm,
        minimum height=5mm,
        align=right
    },
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
  \begin{forest}
  label tree,
  for tree={
    circle,draw,
    s sep'=10pt, 
    edge+=thick,  
    font=\strut\footnotesize\sffamily,
  },
[A, name=lvl0
    [B
      [C, edge label={node[midway,left] {}} ] 
      [D] 
      [E
      [F]
      [G]
      ]
      ]
    [H, name=lvl1 
    [I
      [J]
      [K]
    ] 
      [L] 
      [M, name=lvl2 
      [N, name=lvl3
      ]
      ]
  ] 
]
\node[right=4.05cm of lvl0, Comment] {Level 0};
\node[right=1.75cm of lvl1, Comment] {Level 1};
\node[right=0.6cm of lvl2, Comment] {Level 2};
\node[right=0.6cm of lvl3, Comment] {Level 3};
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This code will work for both beamer as well as other classes.

[image: A tree with level using forest]